# resize, rotate, crop then save images online.... ActionScript or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, image, editor

Which is a better approach for this?

ActionScript3 or JavaScript+PHP?

And if anyone came across an open source tool with either I'd really appreciate it.. after a long search, the only good example i found was this http://www.ajax-image-editor.com but I'd rather have a flash alternative.. Also I don't need all the extra functions such as filters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Flash and Actionscript would certainly have their advantages, but I know no Open Source solution in that field. In Javascript, there is the Prototype based [Cropper](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/). There is at least one more good open product out there, but I forgot the name.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a front-end technology choice. Neither Flash nor JS can store an image on the client side on their own. Both will behave like RPC clients, sending requests to the server to execute.

Whether you choose Flash or JS depends upon your needs (Flash would allow more manipulations than JS) and skills.